# SQL sql query with regexp

Tags: postgresql

I have column like

```
Column1   column 2
Audy.       123
Baza.z.     675
Sco,da@.    432
```

Here I am trying

1. `Select column2 from table where lower(column1)='audy';`
2. `select column2 from table where lower(column1) regexp'[.,]' ='audy';`

I need column data with out special characters in it using either sql or postgre sql and should take regexp from where condition only.

Comment: if you would narrow down OP to one clear question and post desired result, I expect it to be a very easy task to do urgently

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`regex_replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

```
select  column2 
from    table 
where   regexp_replace(lower(column1), '\W', '', 'g') = 'audy'
```

The regex `\W` matches any character that is not a letter or number.  The flag `'g'` (global) means remove all matches, not just the first one.